# deployed in a Adobe ColdFusion environment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html4

Is it possible to be deploy [this theme](http://www.condorthemes.com/flatdream/) in Adobe ColdFusion environment?
Any Suggestions?

Thanks
Sri

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you must have jQuery installed to use BootStrap.  This does not preclude you from using jQuery/BootStrap in conjunction with Coldfusion scripts/tags, though.  Is there any reason you cannot run jQuery within your CF environment?

Comment: You will need jQuery to run Bootstrap JS. If you're just looking for bootstrap CSS, you won't need jQuery. That being said, you should have no issue running jQuery on the clientside of a CF environment.